# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customerService' is defined

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, javabeans

I need help fixing this error I get when trying to deploy my web application into tomcat. Why isn't the customerService bean being defined? Am I missing something in my web.xml or do I have to map the customerService somehow? I am using annotations for mapping. any help would be much appreciated. Here is the error log entry from the localhost log:

Error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customerService' is defined
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4600)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5097)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5092)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customerService' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    ... 21 more

Apr 30, 2012 11:17:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 30, 2012 11:23:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Apr 30, 2012 11:23:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Apr 30, 2012 11:23:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Apr 30, 2012 11:23:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 30, 2012 11:23:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 30, 2012 11:23:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Apr 30, 2012 11:23:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Apr 30, 2012 11:23:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Apr 30, 2012 11:23:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 30, 2012 11:23:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customerService' is defined
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4600)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5097)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5092)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customerService' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    ... 21 more
```

web.xml **(mistest/WebContent/WEB-INF)** **Updated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mistest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>



    <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



 </web-app>
```

customerService

```
package testapp.mis.service;

import java.util.List;

import testapp.mis.domain.Customer;

public interface CustomerService {


    public List<Customer> retrieveAllCustomerNames();
    public List<Customer> retrieveAllCustomerCountries();
    public void createCustomer(Customer customer);
    public List<Customer> retrieveAllCustomers();

}
```

thanks for the help, let me know if I need to put up any other files.

**Edit:** Here is the applicationContext.xml and the customerService Implementation files:

applicationContext.xml **(mistest/WebContent/WEB-INF)** **Updated**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="testapp.mis"/>
    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="0"/>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

customerServiceImpl:

```
package testapp.mis.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import testapp.mis.dao.CustomerDao;
import testapp.mis.domain.Customer;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> retrieveAllCustomerNames() {
        return this.customerDao.getAllCustomerNames();
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> retrieveAllCustomerCountries() {
        return this.customerDao.getAllCustomerCountries();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void createCustomer(Customer customer){
        this.customerDao.saveCustomer(customer);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> retrieveAllCustomers(){
        return this.customerDao.getAllCustomers();
    }

}
```

**Edit2:**

Here is the CustomerController. I added the @Autowired as suggested.

```
package testapp.mis.controller;

//import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.util.List;

import testapp.mis.service.CustomerService;
import testapp.mis.domain.Customer;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {



    /*@Resource(name="customerService")
    private CustomerService customerService;
    */
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;


    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCustomerList(Model model) {
        List<Customer> customers = customerService.retrieveAllCustomers();
        System.out.println("test");
        model.addAttribute("customerList", customers);

        return "customer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCustomer(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("customerAttribute", new Customer());

        return "new-customer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customerAttribute") Customer customer) {
        customerService.createCustomer(customer);

        return "redirect:/mis/customer/list";
    }
}
```

**spring-servlet.xml** (mistest/WebContent/WEB-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

**hibernate-context.xml** (mistest/WebContent/WEB-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      ">

 <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

    <!-- Enables annotations for transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
        p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
        p:packagesToScan="testapp.mis"/>

 <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities--> 
 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
    p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
    p:acquireIncrement="5"
    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
    p:maxPoolSize="100"
    p:maxStatements="50"
    p:minPoolSize="10" />

 <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

</beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml** (mistest/WebContent/WEB-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

   <!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>

    <!-- Remove after testing -->

    <!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
      Existing data will be deleted! -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

/D

Comment: Please add your Spring context file.

Comment: Did you configure CustomerService in xml or annotate with either @Service/@Component/@Repository?

Comment: @sivaprasadreddy.k I annotated my service implementation with "@Service". I added the implementation file in my edit

Comment: It should work... please add your controller :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By reading your exception , It's sure that you forgot to autowire customerService

You should autowire your customerservice .

make following changes in your controller class

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController{

    @Autowired
    private Customerservice customerservice;
......other code......

}
```

Again your service implementation class

write

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
......other code......

.....add transactional methods
}
```

If you are using hibernate make necessary changes in your applicationcontext xml file(configuration of session factory is needed).

you should autowire sessionFactory set method in your DAO mplementation

please find samle application context :

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sparkle" />
    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="0" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" /> -->

     <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">         
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties</value>          

        </list>    
    </property>     
    </bean>




    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />


   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>


</beans>
```

note that i am using jdbc.properties file for jdbc url and driver specification

Comment: @dlinx90: If still facing some exception share your controller class source code

Comment: After adding "@Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;" to my controller and removing the "@Resource" the application is taking forever to deploy into tomcat (it's still not done)

Comment: It may be due to another problem (db access or something).

Comment: @JOHND I tried changing the applicationContext using your updated answer. I am now getting the same error as before.

Comment: which version are you using..??

Comment: @JOHND I am using spring 3. I updated your xsi:schemalocation to fit with my version

Comment: try removing <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> from wb.xml

Comment: please share your updated web.xml and applicationcontext.xml and its location and exact name

Comment: @JOHND I have now updated the files you asked for and added the other config files. Removing the <listener> made the deployment go on forever again. Thanks for taking your time to help me out, much appreciated!

Comment: first rename your application-context to Spring-servlet.xml(name you have mentioned in your web.xml)

Comment: why you have created application-context.xml and spring-servlet.xml create only spring-servlet.xml place it under WEB-INF directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10702/discussion-between-johnd-and-dlinx90)

Comment: first note that applicationContext meaning if your applicationcontxt path is projectABC then your applicationContext.xml is /projectABC-servlet.xml

Comment: @JOHND Yes, I got it working. I hadn't Autowired correctly but as soon as i fixed that it was working :) Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You will have to annotate your service with `@Service` since you have said `I am using annotations for mapping`

Comment: Do I have to do this for the interface too? (I have annotated the implementation) Looking at this example [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/adding-crud-capability-spring) they did not annotate the Service Interface

Comment: Have you correctly configured the base-package to look for spring beans?

Comment: the base package is configured to look for spring beans in testapp.mis which should be correct

Comment: I just ran into exactly the same problem - `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean ...` - with some Oracle Fusion-generated Java code.  The solution was simply to add `@Service` annotation to the offending class.  Voila - fixed!  Thank you, mprabhat!

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that your applicationContext.xml file is loaded by specifying it in your web.xml file:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another possibility:
Spring initializes bean by type not by name if you don't define bean with a name, which is ok if you use it by its type:

Producer:

```
@Service
public void FooServiceImpl implements FooService{}
```

Consumer:

```
@Autowired
private FooService fooService;
```

or

```
@Autowired
private void setFooService(FooService fooService) {}
```

but not ok if you use it by name:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
ctx.getBean("fooService");
```

It would complain: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'fooService' is defined`
In this case, assigning name to `@Service("fooService")` would make it work.